# Hibernate java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast.. Class cast exception

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I am trying to read certain values from the hsql db and these values are returned as map with key and value. I have one more method which will accept these map values and will iterate through it and will fetch certain values based on the conditions.After this it will add all these values to a list. for me the condition and the first method is working fine but while adding the values to the list I am facing the class cast exception

Method which reads values from the table:

```
List<EntityMap> sample = session.createQuery(" FROM EntityMap order by if.ifName").list();
for (Iterator<EntityMap> iterator = sample.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    entityMap = (EntityMap) iterator.next();
    if (IfName != entityMap.getIf().getIfName().toString()) {
        IfName = entityMap.getIf().getIfName().toString();
        entitymapobject = new ArrayList<EntityMap>();
    }
    entitymapobject.add(entityMap);
    EntityMaplist.put(entityMap.getIf().getIfName(),entitymapobject);
}
tx.commit();
```

This method is returning a map and it has the values which is fetched from the db. After that i am trying to extract certain values based on some conditions.In this I am calling the above method and i am iterating through it

```
proertyMap = listPROPERTNAMES();
System.out.println("inside loadproperty");
for (Iterator<Integer> itr1 = srcEntityIDList.iterator(); itr1.hasNext();) {
    Integer aInteger = itr1.next();
    for (Map.Entry<Long, List<PropertyMap>> entry : proertyMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(aInteger);
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        Long aLong = entry.getKey();
        if  (aLong.equals(Long.valueOf(aInteger)))  {
            System.out.println("values are equal");
            trgtPropNameList.add(( (PropertyMap) entry.getValue()).getTgtpropnm());
          }
      }
    }
    return trgtPropNameList;

    if (tx != null)
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return EntityMaplist;
}
```

Here while trying to add the values to the list (trgtPropNameList) I am getting a class cast exception. My POJO class which has the setter and the  getter methods is

```
public class PropertyMap implements java.io.Serializable {

    private PropertyMapId id;
    private EntityMap entityMap;
    private String tgtpropnm;
    private String splitrule;
    private String combinerule;
    private String createdby;
    private Date createdon;

    public PropertyMap() {
    }

    public PropertyMap(PropertyMapId id, EntityMap entityMap) {
        this.id = id;
        this.entityMap = entityMap;
    }

    public PropertyMap(PropertyMapId id, EntityMap entityMap, String tgtpropnm,
            String splitrule, String combinerule, String createdby,
            Date createdon) {
        this.id = id;
        this.entityMap = entityMap;
        this.tgtpropnm = tgtpropnm;
        this.splitrule = splitrule;
        this.combinerule = combinerule;
        this.createdby = createdby;
        this.createdon = createdon;
    }

    public PropertyMapId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(PropertyMapId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public EntityMap getEntityMap() {
        return this.entityMap;
    }

    public void setEntityMap(EntityMap entityMap) {
        this.entityMap = entityMap;
    }

    public String getTgtpropnm() {
        return this.tgtpropnm;
    }

    public void setTgtpropnm(String tgtpropnm) {
        this.tgtpropnm = tgtpropnm;
    }

    public String getSplitrule() {
        return this.splitrule;
    }

    public void setSplitrule(String splitrule) {
        this.splitrule = splitrule;
    }

    public String getCombinerule() {
        return this.combinerule;
    }

    public void setCombinerule(String combinerule) {
        this.combinerule = combinerule;
    }

    public String getCreatedby() {
        return this.createdby;
    }

    public void setCreatedby(String createdby) {
        this.createdby = createdby;
    }

    public Date getCreatedon() {
        return this.createdon;
    }

    public void setCreatedon(Date createdon) {
        this.createdon = createdon;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entry.getValue()` is an object of type `List<PropertyMap>` and not `PropertyMap`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't cast it just construct and fill a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
trgtPropNameList.add(( (PropertyMap) entry.getValue()).getTgtpropnm());
```

to

```
for(PropertyMap map : entry.getValue(){
    trgtPropNameList.add(((PropertyMap)map).getTgtpropnm());
}
```

Should fix the casting problem.